# Update a property value without adding an additional value, in gremlin_python

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

In the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-differences.html) under **Updating a Vertex Property**, it is mentioned that one can *"update a property value without adding an additional value to the set of values"*
by doing
`g.V('exampleid01').property(single, 'age', 25)`

In **gremlin_python**, I am unable to run a query like the above.
I get the error:

```
update_prop_overwrite = g.V().hasLabel('placeholder-vertex').property(single,'maker','unknown').next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'single' is not defined
```

How can I resolve this so that I can replace a Vertex property value in Neptune?
Without `single` the query will append the new property value to the property key if a value exists already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be sure to import `single` which is seen [here in the code](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/d1a3fa147d1f009ae57274827c9b59426dfc6e58/gremlin-python/src/main/jython/gremlin_python/process/traversal.py#L127) and can be imported with:

```
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Cardinality
```

however TinkerPop documentation recommends importing all such classes with:

```
statics.load_statics(globals())
```

You can read more about that [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_static_enums_and_methods).

Comment: thanks!, `statics.load_statics(globals())` worked but `from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Cardinality` didn't seem to.. Not sure why, maybe its an AWS Neptune thing

Answer (score 1):

```
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Cardinality

g.V().hasLabel('placeholder-vertex').property(Cardinality.single,'maker','unknown').next()
```

This should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Import `statics` from `gremlin_python`

```
from gremlin_python import statics
statics.load_statics(globals())


update_prop_overwrite = g.V().hasLabel('placeholder-vertex').property(single,'maker','unknown').next()
```